# "Android library projects cannot be launched" in Facebook Android tutorial

Tags: android, facebook

I installed both the Android and Facebook SDKs. I did all the steps in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sdk till Step 6.3. 


In step 6.4, when I try to run the project in Emulator (Using Android 4.0.3), I get "Android library projects cannot be launched" and the project doesn't proceed further. Even the logcat doesn't have any content.

Can someone please tell me what may be the problem?


Thanks

Souvik

Answer (score 4):

Folow these steps

```
 1. In the Package Explorer, right-click the library project and select
    Properties.
 2. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and 
     locate the Library properties at right.
 3. Select the "is Library" checkbox and click Apply.
 4. Click OK to close the Properties window.
```

Answer (score 3):

Library projects cant be launched. you can use that in your project and run your project adding it as library.

Comment: thaks Seshu , but we need to make project first as library project , we can set from project property..android at down side check it with library...hope this help more

Comment: @John Watson, Its ok if you can't launch this FB library. You will not be able to do it as library projects cannot be launched. But if you create your own project which uses thislibrary then you shd be able to launch your project :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better to have the Facebook sdk as a Library so you can simply #import the sdk file into eclipse.  Simple.  I spent a day trying to get the sample source into a project to test the post on wall.  I get the app to run but no breakpoints get called in my project, I had to create the build.xml and not sure if that is the cause.  It would be better if the whole test project files were included instead of only the resources and jar files. That way you could just import everything and it should work within 5 mins.